# Cucumber Java latest version

Tags: java, cucumber

From where I can get latest Test Runner class format and cucumber dependencies for Java. I have old dependencies and it was working but now these are too old and does not. I created my new POM file but now my TestRunner file have red error lines and I can not run my tests. I have copied my old and new dependencies below. Please let me know what I am missing here. Do I need more dependencies or these are enough.

Old POM: (with old dependencies I got the following error when I try to run my feature file:

cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unknown option: --plugin

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

NEW POM: (if I use following  new dependencies, my TESTRUNNER  has red lines under"@CucumberOptions"




 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Might be good to start from scratch and do the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: Did you (auto)import the new dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

No, I manually update my pom.xml file. Got the new dependencies from maven repository.